# Serialize a whole collection to XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xstream, jaxb2

I have the following list from JavaFX:

```
ObservableList<Expense> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Does anybody know, how I can transfer the whole collection to XML?

If I could do this, deserializing should be really easy.

I tried it with XStream and Jaxb. I looked at multiple tutorials, but I didn't come to a good result.

It's possible to serialize the Expense Objects on their own, but not a whole list (without using a for-loop).

Do you have any idea?

Comment: There always has to be one root in XML. That's the format definition. You can always use some wrapping object with a list property (attribute) and serialize it as root.

Comment: You may find the following post I wrote helpful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/creating-generic-list-wrapper-in-jaxb.html